# Cannot install jekyll as it complaints: 'requires Ruby version >= 2.3.0'

Tags: ruby, jekyll, rvm, bundler

I have only one ruby version installed:

```
$ rvm list
=* ruby-2.5.7 [ x86_64 ]

# => - current
# =* - current && default
#  * - default
```

But any time I install jekyll or bundler I got complain of an older version.

```
$ sudo gem install bundler
ERROR:  Error installing bundler:
    bundler requires Ruby version >= 2.3.0.
```

Unable to find the reason.
Operating system: CentOS

Comment: When you use `sudo gem install` you may be using the system Ruby version which is different than the rvm one. Try `sudo ruby -v`

Answer (score 5):

When using RVM as your Ruby manager you do not (and should not) use `sudo`. Sudo runs everything under the `root` account. But RVM is installed under your own user account, and therefore `sudo` is not needed, and will in fact circumvent RVM if used.

So, just drop the `sudo` part, and if RVM is installed properly, everything should start working correctly:

```
gem install bundler     # <- no sudo needed
```

Answer (score 0):

I bit late, but I had the same problem and couldn't find an answer documented anywhere.
The problem is that `sudo` uses a different version of ruby than what `rvm` has set. You can see this by comparing `ruby -v` and `sudo ruby -v`.

To solve this, try `rvmsudo gem install bundler`. This causes `sudo` to use the version of ruby that `rvm` expects.

Read more here: https://rvm.io/integration/sudo